# os.walk/scandir slow on network drive

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-file, os.walk, scandir

I trying to find all `.xlsm` files (and get their stats) on the network drive `O:\` provided they are not in a folder called, `Test`. I was using `os.walk` and switched to `scandir.walk` because it's faster. I am now just limited by the network speed. This code seems to have a lot of interaction between script and network drive. My code is below. Is there a way to speed to this up maybe using a batch file? I'm on Windows.

```
from scandir import scandir, walk
import sys

def subdirs(path):
    for path, folders, files in walk(path):
        if 'Test' not in path:
            for sub_files in scandir(path):
                if '.xlsm' in sub_files.path:
                    yield subfiles.stat()

for i in subdirs('O:\\'):
    print i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are double-scanning every path, once implicitly via `walk`, then again by explicitly re-`scandir`ing the `path` `walk` returned for no reason. `walk` already returned the `files`, so the inner loop can avoid a double-scan by just using what it was given:

```
def subdirs(path):
    for path, folders, files in walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if '.xlsm' in file:
                yield os.path.join(path, file)
```

To address updated question, you'll probably want to either copy the existing `scandir.walk` code and modify it to return `list`s of `DirEntry`s instead of `list`s of names, or write similar special cased code for your specific needs; either way, this will allow you to avoid double-scanning, while keeping `scandir`'s special low overhead behavior. For example:

```
def scanwalk(path, followlinks=False):
    '''Simplified scandir.walk; yields lists of DirEntries instead of lists of str'''
    dirs, nondirs = [], []
    for entry in scandir.scandir(path):
        if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=followlinks):
            dirs.append(entry)
        else:
            nondirs.append(entry)
    yield path, dirs, nondirs
    for dir in dirs:
        for res in scanwalk(dir.path, followlinks=followlinks):
            yield res
```

You can then replace your use of `walk` with it like this (I also added code that prunes directories with `Test` in them since all directories and files under them would have been rejected by your original code, but you'd still traverse them unnecessarily):

```
def subdirs(path):
    # Full prune if the path already contains Test
    if 'Test' in path:
        return
    for path, folders, files in scanwalk(path):
        # Remove any directory with Test to prevent traversal
        folders[:] = [d for d in folders if 'Test' not in d.name]
        for file in files:
            if '.xlsm' in file.path:
                yield file.stat()  # Maybe just yield file to get raw DirEntry?

for i in subdirs('O:\\'):
    print i
```

BTW, you may want to double check that you've properly installed/built the C accelerator for `scandir`, `_scandir`. If `_scandir` isn't built, the `scandir` module provides fallback implementations using `ctypes`, but they're significantly slower, which could explain performance problems. Try running `import _scandir` in an interactive Python session; if it raises `ImportError`, then you don't have the accelerator, so you're using the slow fallback implementation.

Comment: The only problem with this is that I loose the other variables associated with files that I would normally need to get via `os.stat()` see: https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir

Comment: @user2242044: I know about `scandir` (I evangelize it regularly), but your original code was only `yield`ing the path, not the `DirEntry` object; you weren't making use of the free/cached `stat` behavior. If you need the `stat` info, you may want to copy the `scandir.walk` implementation and modify it to return `list`s of the raw `DirEntry` objects for `dirnames` and `filenames` instead of returning a `list` of `str`. That gets the best of both worlds; single pass scanning, no repetitive `stat`ing. Or just implement your own recursive function that specializes to your use case.

Comment: @ShadowRanger..Thanks for the clarification. I tried to simplify the code for the SO question, but think I lost some of the intent. The double iteration was because I was trying to avoid iterating over some folders and I do want to the stat yield. Modified the original question. Thanks!

Comment: @user2242044: Gotcha. Updated answer with example of how you'd implement a `walk`-like function that `yield`ed `list`s of `DirEntry` instead of `list`s of `str`. Removing the double-scan should make it as fast as possible in Python; `scandir` is using `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` already, which is the most efficient Windows file scanning API (doubly so when you need `stat` info, or when the directory being scanned is high latency; it reduces the number of round trips to something closer to one per directory, instead of one per directory + one per file). No batch file techniques will beat it.

Comment: @user2242044: I also added a note about the C accelerator at the bottom; you'll want to verify you actually built the accelerator. Without it, `scandir` would still save you network traffic, but it would add a ton of overhead to the normal code overhead.

Comment: Thanks for that added note, in PyCharm it says no module named `_scandir` yet no import error in this when run or in the Python IDLE, so I assume I have it? Also, you mentioned it was faster than batch filing. My thought there was something like `dir /s/b .\*.xlsm`

Comment: @user2242044: `dir` is implemented in terms of `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`, just like `scandir` (because of this, it doesn't take noticeable additional time to do `dir` vs. `dir /b` even on a high latency network share, even though the former echoes `stat` info which would otherwise require a round trip). While it's implemented entirely in C/C++ (no Python byte code execution overhead), to actually use the output, you'd need to read from its `stdout` and parse in Python (or whatever language you like) which would undo any savings you might achieve.

Comment: also getting a couple of errors `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'name'`. That should just be `d`? The same error applies to the `file.path`.

Comment: @user2242044: `d` should be a `DirEntry`, did you use the code as I wrote it (using the custom `scanwalk` over `scandir.walk`)? The whole point of `scanwalk` is to get `DirEntry`s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105049/discussion-between-user2242044-and-shadowranger).

Comment: originally posted in chat, but this seems useful to others reading this so posting here. two questions: 1. This code seems to look in specified folder and sub-folder only, not all sub-folder levels. Is that correct? 2. In the scanwalk() function, you have two yield functions (not separated out by an if-else statement). I'm not seeing a situation in which the 'yield res' would be reached.

Comment: @user2242044: Responded at length in chat, but in summary: It recurses through the entire tree, not just the provided folder and a single level of sub-folders. `subdirs` prunes directories with `Test` in their name, preventing recursion into them, but if you have a directory `C:\a\b\c\d` (no other directories involved), then you should get `path` and `DirEntry` info for `C:\a`, then `C:\a\b`, then `C:\a\b\c`, then `C:\a\b\c\d`, and so on, however deep the tree goes (though you may have handle exhaustion issues if the depth of the tree is thousands of directories deep).

Comment: @user2242044: As for #2, you need to understand what `yield` does to a function; just because you hit the first `yield` doesn't mean the function stops forever, it just means it pauses until the caller iterates the resulting generator again. See [What does the yield keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python). The second `yield` will execute as many times as there are `dirs` (if the caller mutates a `yield`ed `dirs`, this prunes the set of sub-directories to recurse into), as long as you keep iterating.